# how to subscribe to an observable in a different service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that simply says if a user is logged in or not.
It gets updated from another service which does the http request to verify the user.

I want a nav bar component to update the ui to show the user a login or logout button based on the observable (BehaviorSubject) .

(in my bootstrap function I am injecting Auth)

nav-main.component.ts

```
import {Auth} from '../services/auth.service';

constructor ( public _auth: Auth) {
   this._auth.check().subscribe(data =>{console.log(data)})
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()

export class Auth {
    subject: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
    loggedIn:boolean = false;

    constructor(){
        this.subject.next(this.loggedIn);
    }

    login(id_token){
        ...
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.subject.next(this.loggedIn);
    }

    check() {
        return this.subject.asObservable().startWith(this.loggedIn);     
    }
}
```

login.service.ts

```
import {Injectable, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http,Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppInjectorService} from './app-injector.service';
import {Auth} from './auth.service';
import {UserService} from './user.service'
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class LogInUserService {
  auth:Auth;
  injector:Injector;
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    // let injector: Injector= AppInjectorService();
    this.injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([Auth]);

    this.auth = this.injector.get(Auth);
}

logInUser(data) {
...
return this.http.post(this._authUrl, body, { headers:headers})
    .map(function(res){ return <UserService> res.json().data;})
    .do(data => this.logIn(data))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
//on success tell the auth.login the public key
logIn(data){
    this.auth.login(data.publicKey);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Inject(Auth) _auth looked to have done the trick.

nav-main.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from 'angular2/core';

_auth;

constructor(public _router: Router,
            public _service: IsActiveRouteService,
            @Inject(Auth) _auth){

    this._auth = _auth;//@Inject(Auth) _auth did the trick
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._auth.check()
                .subscribe(data =>{
                    console.log('nav init check() '+data)
    });
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()

export class Auth {
    isLoggedIn:boolean = false;
    logIn$: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.isLoggedIn);
    externalBS;

    constructor() {
        this.logIn$.asObservable();
        this.externalBS = this.logIn$;
    }


    login(id_token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('id_token',id_token);
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.logIn$.next(this.isLoggedIn);
    }


    logout() {
        window.localStorage.setItem('id_token','');
        this.isLoggedIn = false;            
    }

    check() {
        return this.externalBS.asObservable().startWith(this.isLoggedIn);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need isLoggedIn. You could  this.logIn.next(false), couldn't you? Why do you have startWith(this.isLoggedIn)? I don't understand this.